# Как сделать кастомный SeekBar без костылей с Android 4.0+?

Tags: android

Требуется создать `Seekbar` со следующими параметрами

- Прозрачный `background`
- Серая полоса для второго прогресса
- Белая полоса для главного прогресса
- Белый круг для ползунка

В Интернете очень много информации по этому виджету, но я не могу найти подходящее, не уверен в актуальности решений, какой способ будет работать безоговорочно для Android 4.0+ Кода не надо, только покажите куда копать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извиняюсь, надо было сразу либу искать.
https://github.com/ahmedrizwan/SeekBarCompat/blob/master/README.md